# Upgrade neo4j v2.2.4 to latest version (3.0) on ubuntu

Tags: neo4j

I wanted to upgrade neo4j v2.2.4 to latest version 3.0 
I have run command

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade  neo4j 3.0
```

It gives the following error

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcuda1-340 : Breaks: libcuda-5.0-1
                Breaks: libcuda-5.5-1
                Breaks: libcuda-6.0-1
                Breaks: libcuda-6.5-1
 libcuda1-340-updates : Breaks: libcuda-5.0-1
                        Breaks: libcuda-5.5-1
                        Breaks: libcuda-6.0-1
                        Breaks: libcuda-6.5-1
 nvidia-340 : Conflicts: nvidia-persistenced
              Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
 nvidia-340-updates : Conflicts: nvidia-persistenced
                      Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
 nvidia-libopencl1-340 : Conflicts: libopencl1
 nvidia-libopencl1-340-updates : Conflicts: libopencl1
 nvidia-opencl-icd-340 : Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
 nvidia-opencl-icd-340-updates : Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

.

Can any one give me solution for same?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` before trying to update Neo4j?

Comment: @4M01 - yes , I have run this command before neo4j update

Comment: This looks more like a general ubuntu related question. Can you amend the output of `apt-cache policy` to your question?

Comment: Looks rather like some of your other packages have a dependency issue. What are the listed dependencies for neo4j?